# Golang generate same encryption across different machines

Tags: encryption, go, aes

I have a go script that uses crypto/aes to encrypt and decrypt a plaintext.

https://play.golang.org/p/le_-uuzWN4

I want this script to be used across different machines and produce the same encrypted text. I thought that by having a custom IV it would result in a consistent encryption no matter where. 
Right now it yields in different results on the go playground versus on https://repl.it/languages/go

Is it possible to produce consistent encryption or will it always be different due to internal implementation (like encryption salt, etc..)

Also, what exactly is IV, I'm still confused about that. The doc doesnt really explain what it is

Comment: An IV is a nonce. Reusing an IV defeats its purpose and can break your encryption.

Comment: that makes so much more sense now. Does this mean that there is no way to generate the same consistent encryption?

Comment: Not safely, why would you want to do that? Producing predictable output defeats the purpose of encrypting it. This sounds like you have a different problem you're trying to solve. Are you looking for a cryptographic hash function instead?

Comment: I suppose. The idea is to encrypt UserIDs in a database where UserIDs are supposed to be keys

Comment: I think you could use a hash of the username to generate a predictable IV, but I feel like using a hash by itself would be safer.

Comment: Don't reuse the IV if you're encrypting in CFB mode. As JimB said, it must be used only once when the key stays the same. If the IV is reused you're creating a multipad which can be used by an attacker to recover the full plaintext only by knowing some properties of the plaintext.

Comment: The CFB implementation in Go uses a 128 bit segment/feedback size. Which means that it needs some padding. The decryption might use junk bytes when the padding bytes are missing. But this shouldn't be possible in Go.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out why it was generating a different cipher text each time. The IV is randomized with this statement

```
if _, err := io.ReadFull(rand.Reader, iv); err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
```

Removing it will keep the IV constant and it will generate the same encryption given the same Key an IV on any machine

Comment: Do not do this. Just prefix the encrypted data with the IV  for use during decryption, the IV does not need to be secret.

Comment: This is indeed required in some implementations. For e.g., I'm using PayTM as a payment gateway in one of my applications and there the IV is supposed to be fixed.